# How To Join Many Tables In Linq Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I Got This Lambda Expression But Does Not Work Correctly.Does Not Return Any Thing.Would You Help me Please on this:

```
    var query = db.Cheque
                    .Join(db.Contracts,
                    C => C.ContractIDRef,
                    Con => Con.ContractID,
                    (C, Con) => new { Cheques1 = C, Contracts1 = Con })
                    .Join(db.Parties,
                    Con => Con.Contracts1.ContractID,
                    Pt => Pt.ContractIDRef,
                    (Con, Pt) => new { Contract2 = Con, Parites1 = Pt })
                    .Join(db.Persons,
                    Pt => Pt.Parites1.PartyIDRef,
                    P => P.PersonID,
                    (Pt, P) => new { Parites2 = Pt, Persons1 = P })
                    .Join(db.Company,
                    Pt => Pt.Parites2.Parites1.CompanyIDRef,
                    Com => Com.CompanyID,
                    (Pt, Com) => new { Parites3 = Pt, Company1 = Com })
                    .Join(db.Bank,
                    C => C.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.BankIDRef,
                    B => B.BankID,
                    (C, B) => new { Cheque2 = C, Bank1 = B })
                    .Join(db.Flats,
                    Con => Con.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Contracts1.FlatIDRef,
                    F => F.FlatID,
                    (Con, F) => new { Contract3 = Con, Flat1 = F })
                    .Join(db.Projects,
                    F => F.Flat1.ProjectIDRef,
                    Pr => Pr.ProjectID,
                    (F, Pr) =>
                    new
                    {
                        ChequeNumber = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.ChequeNo,
                        ChequeIDRef = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.ChequeIDRef,
                        ChequePrice = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.Amount,
                        BankName = F.Contract3.Bank1.BankName,
                        BranchName = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.BranchName,
                        ChequeDate = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.ChequeDate,
                        AccountNumber = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.AccNo,
                        AccountOwner = F.Contract3.Cheque2.Parites3.Parites2.Contract2.Cheques1.ChequeOwnerName,
                    }
                    )
`.Where(Total => SelectedChequesList.Contains(Total.ChequeIDRef.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: You could start removing the ToList and viewing the query (query.ToString() should contain the SQL query) and try do debug it.

Comment: bubi
Thanks ,Very Usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with converting the above to the query syntax. While I'm a fan of the method syntax, using it in a complex queries involving multiple joins is a real pain. I needed a lot of time to read and try to follow the above query, so let do that:

```
var query =
    from cheque in db.Cheque
    join contract in db.Contracts on cheque.ContractIDRef equals contract.ContractID
    join party in db.Parties on contract.ContractID equals party.ContractIDRef
    join person in db.Persons on party.PartyIDRef equals person.PersonID
    join company in db.Companies on party.CompanyIDRef equals company.CompanyID
    join bank in db.Bank on cheque.BankIDRef equals bank.BankID
    join flat in db.Flats on contract.FlatIDRef equals flat.FlatID
    join project in db.Projects on flat.ProjectIDRef equals project.ProjectID
    where SelectedChequesList.Contains(cheque.ChequeIDRef.Value)
    select new
    {
        ChequeNumber = cheque.ChequeNo,
        ChequeIDRef = cheque.ChequeIDRef,
        ChequePrice = cheque.Amount,
        BankName = bank.BankName,
        BranchName = cheque.BranchName,
        ChequeDate = cheque.ChequeDate,
        AccountNumber = cheque.AccNo,
        AccountOwner = cheque.ChequeOwnerName,
    };
```

Now, one thing that can be seen is that most of the joins are not used. But let assume they are needed for some reason. Note that all the joins are `INNER` joins, so any of them can cause the query to return empty result if there is no matching record.

The problem is most probably in this join

```
join person in db.Persons on party.PartyIDRef equals person.PersonID
```

Instead of `PartyIDRef` I guess it should be something like `PersonIDRef`.

Comment: Strange thinking, what is more important, a lambda expression or working query? But you missed the main point which is potentially incorrect field used in one of the joins. Anyway, just fix `Pt => Pt.Parites1.PartyIDRef` in your lambda then. It took me a long time to find it originally inside your lambda, and the same now to finding it again.